# How to get changeset information from tfs using Java tfs-sdk

Tags: java, eclipse, tfs

I tried with the below code

```
     TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc =
                new TFSTeamProjectCollection(URIUtils.newURI(COLLECTION_URL), credentials );

            VersionControlClient srcctrl = tpc.getVersionControlClient();
         Changeset[] chngset;
        try {
            chngset = srcctrl.queryHistory("http://******/tfs/SpectaTestCollection/", LatestVersionSpec.INSTANCE, 0, RecursionType.FULL, null, new DateVersionSpec("6/10/2014"), LatestVersionSpec.INSTANCE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, false, true, false, true);

             for(Changeset ch : chngset)
                {
                    System.out.println("Change Set ID : "+ ch.getChangesetID());
                    System.out.println("Owner : "+ ch.getOwner());
                }
        } catch (ServerPathFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But eveytime getting this error : There is no working folder mapping for D:\WorkSpace\test-workspace\tfsplay.game\http:********\tfs\SpectaTestCollection.

where "D:\WorkSpace\test -workspace\tfsplay.game" is my local workspace.

can anyone help me in guiding to the right way for doing this

Answer (score 4):

Don't pass a URL to the `queryHistory` method, pass a server path or a local path.

You're getting this error because you have passed a path that is not a server path (does not start with `$/`), so the system is trying to understand what server path you have mapped to `http://...etc`.  Since that URL is also not a local path, you have gotten that error.

If you want to see all history, pass the server path `$/`.

Comment: when using tfs sdk, do we need to perform login logout manually? as tfsteamprojectcollection object performs authentication, apart from this is it required to perform logout or connection termination, if yes then your help with sample will be apreciated

Comment: Yes, dont pass the whole url , instead use project path ,( Eg. $/ParentFolderOne/ChildFolderOne/ChildFolderTwo/.... etc

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TestTfsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 


        Credentials cred=new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username","password") ;

        TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc =new TFSTeamProjectCollection(URIUtils.newURI("Application_Collection_url")
            , cred);


        WorkItemClient workItemClient = tpc.getWorkItemClient(); 

        Changeset[] chngset=null;

        LabelSpec lable=new LabelSpec("tfs_start_Label", null);

        LabelSpec lable1=new LabelSpec("tfs_end_label", null);

        try {

            chngset = tpc.getVersionControlClient().queryHistory("$project_directory", LatestVersionSpec.INSTANCE, 0, 
                RecursionType.FULL, null,new LabelVersionSpec(lable1), new LabelVersionSpec(lable), Integer.MAX_VALUE, true, true, false, true);

        } catch (ServerPathFormatException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(Changeset ch : chngset)
        {
            System.out.println("Change Set ID : "+ ch.getChangesetID());

            System.out.println("Owner : "+ ch.getOwner());


            Change changes[]=ch.getChanges();

            System.out.println("Date : "+ new     Date(ch.getDate().getTimeInMillis()));


            for(Change chang:changes)
            {
                System.out.println(chang.getItem().getServerItem());;

                //System.out.println("Owner : "+         chang.getItem().getItemType().toString());

            }
         }  



   }

}
```

Comment: we can also query changeset based on diffrent criteria like between date, label.